# Deserialization fails when there is no default constructor

Tags: java, deserialization, fastjson

I 'm trying to use Fastjson library for JSON serialization.
When I try to deserialize , it fails showing no default constructor error.
Note: My class here is a toy example. I realty, it contains so many references to other classes which are in other maven projects  and its practically not possible to modify every class.

Here is the code.

```
Student s = new Student("vineel", "20");
String hell = JSON.toJSONString(s);
Student model2 = JSON.parseObject(hell, Student.class);
System.out.println(model2);

public class Student {

private String name;
private String age;
Student(String name,String age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}
@override
public String toString() {
return "Student [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
public String getAge() {
return age;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
this.age = age;
}

}
```

**Here is the error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: default constructor not found. class com.alibaba.fastjson.Student
at com.alibaba.fastjson.util.JavaBeanInfo.build(JavaBeanInfo.java:467)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.util.JavaBeanInfo.build(JavaBeanInfo.java:213)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.createJavaBeanDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:656)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.getDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:573)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.ParserConfig.getDeserializer(ParserConfig.java:386)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser.parseObject(DefaultJSONParser.java:658)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:365)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:269)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON.java:488)
at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.main(JSON.java:1068)
```

Comment: Yup, it certainly does. You can make the default constructor private if you don't want it to be used elsewhere.

Comment: So add a default constructor.

Comment: Thats not possible @daniu

Comment: Not possible??? Why?

Comment: The class I m trying to deserialize depends on so many libraries and I don't want to keep adding default constructors every-where and its not practically possible.

Comment: Looking at Fastjson's number of open issues about this (among which I think I see yours raised a month ago), I don't think you have much choice.

Comment: Switch to Jackson :)

Comment: @user4654 given that this is not configurable in the library, you don't want to use another library and you don't want to change your code, only one solution comes to my mind - make your own copy of the library and modify it. I will skip a big lit of disadvantages of going down this road, but in general it is possible to create the object without calling its constructor using `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory` (which also has some disadvantages, see https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So create a TO class.

```
Student model2 = JSON.parseObject(hell, StudentTO.class).asStudent();
System.out.println(model2);

public class StudentTO {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Student asStudent() {
        return new Student(name, age);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to pretty much duplicate every serializable class, it easier to just add another constructor in each of them...

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Sure, but that advice was already met with "I don't want to".

Comment: There are so many references inside my actual class. I can't  go to every library and keep modifying every class that needs be done. I m looking for a solution where in which we can configure etc and get the deserialization done.

Comment: @user4654 maybe you should look for other json serialiser which allow to configure it? `gson` and `jackson` are two most popular ones, but I don't remember whether they can be configured to not require default constructor.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak  The performance of this library is much much better.  That's very important for the problem I 'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Change constructor to.

```
@JsonCreator
public Student(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") String age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```